# Why is display:table-cell affected by elements in other cells

Tags: css, css-tables

In a CSS table, can somebody help me **understand** why a padded element in the first column will affect a div in the second column?

Here's an example where a paragraph has padding set. The DIV in the right column is also -incorrectly- padded. I had similar problems when specifying line-height on the left column content but simplified the example for this question.

http://jsfiddle.net/APXT7/2/

There are many similar/related questions about table-cell but I couldn't find one that specifically addresses this question.

Comment: Interesting. I had never seen such an effect.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @j08691 I don't want the gap above the text in the right 'cell'. I actually want this to be a div with a background image but it's simplified in the example to demonstrate the problem

Comment: So doing a `vertical-align:top` on the cell class isn't what you want (http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/APXT7/4/) ? Since these divs are being displayed as table cells, I wasn't sure if you tried that.

Comment: @j08691 You're absolutely right. Thanks very much - I got lost in the weeds on this.

Comment: I should have tried that after @BoltClock explained what was happening.

Comment: OK I'll post that as an answer just for future visitors and if you feel it answers the question you can select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely an issue of line height, rather than one of padding. That means that, although you may suspect, no padding is actually being propagated to your right column (the computed value is still zero). I would still call it a *side effect* of adjusting the padding on your `p` elements.

The padding on the top and bottom of your `p` elements pushes their baseline down. This causes the baseline of other "cells" on the same line/row to shift as well. Of course, you can find all the nitty gritty outlined in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout), but since both "cells" have the same vertical alignment (`baseline`), they have to line up when one is shifted.

Comment: I feel bound to accept your answer as you offered a great explanation... although I'm now left with the follow-up question as the best approach to adjusting line-height differently in adjacent 'cells'. It seems that the right cell is only affected by the FIRST element in the right cell. [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nickpearce/qnCkd/1). I will create a new question.

Answer (score 9):

You can probably use the vertical-align property (`vertical-align:top`) on the cell class or either div like [jsfiddle.net/j08691/APXT7/4](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/APXT7/4). Since these divs are being displayed as table cells, this may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @j08691; this definitely answers my follow-up question but to be strict the first answer addressed my original question of 'why?'.

Answer (score 1):

I found a hack that "fixes" this but don't know why. First thing inside the `<div class='cell'>` put `<div class='hack'>&nbsp;</div>` class hack is `.hack { height: 0; }` This works if put in left or right cell

Comment: I believe your answer displays as intended now.  You are free to [edit] more if needed.  Thanks for answering!